# Uploading file(pandas) creates parser error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

Uploading a simple CSV file gives me a parser error and I can't tell why. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Big data\LinearRegression_ScikitLearn.txt',index_col = 0)
```

It returns this error:

> Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 2

The csv file text is below and there is only one seperator on line 4:

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "## Linear regression models with scikit-learn\n",
    "\n",
    "In this lecture we are going to learn:\n",
    "\n",
    "- How to run a scatter plot of two variables to check for correlation.\n",
    "- How to estimate a linear regression model with the **scikit-learn** package.\n",
    "- How to forecast based on a linear regression model. \n",
    "\n",
  ....
```

Comment: That's not a CSV file, it's JSON.

Comment: `import json` and `json.loads(infile.loads(open(r'C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Big data\LinearRegression_ScikitLearn.txt').read()))`

Comment: ` import json and
    with open(r'C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Bigdata\LinearRegression_ScikitLearn.txt') as f:
        data = json.load(f)`